# Wordpress Plug-In or Post Template for Maintaining Site Look and Feel but Page/Post having own Menu

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for Wordpress Plug-In or Post Template for maintaining site look and feel but a section Page having its own sub-menu.

I have a header / footer theme on the site with a column'd mid-page.

I have tried [Easy Responsive Tabs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-responsive-tabs/) and it so far is not well liked, clashes with the theme, and have constant issues with it truly being responsive on some systems so it basically doesn't work. I think in the future it has potential but right now it does not meet our needs. Essentially an iframe but not.

I am hoping to find something that is easy to manage and facilitates a sub-theme / brand.

The following is a basic overview of what I am trying to do.

The BLUE section will always be the primary brand.
The RED section are the sub-brand which a static division sub-menu, assuming down by a page template or plugin. 
The GREEN section will be dynamic content that is populated by assigning it to a word press post category OR brings up a static page by choosing a menu item.

There would need to be multiple divisions, say 4.

[image]

> Question: Is anyone aware of an easy and manageable way to do this whether it be a Wordpress Plug-in (free or paid), a Post Template that can be downloaded (including paid), or a semi-commercial solution that still allows me perform this with me hosting all content?